# How can I create a holding page in my React app?

Tags: reactjs

I have a React app which is stored in an AWS CodeCommit repo, and I want to create a holding page for it. Basically, a page called `maintenance.html`, which I can redirect to when the rest of the site is down for maintenance.  I'm not sure how to do this.

I've created maintenance.html and put it in the root folder, but when I go to `mysite.com/maintenance` it redirects me to `mysite.com`.  I assume this is because React kicks in, doesn't recognise the route, and therefore redirects me.

Is there a way to create a single page in the root of a React application, which the user can navigate to directly?

Comment: how is this page served?

Comment: I'm not sure... I don't do the deployment, and it's something I don't really understand much about.  It's a standard React app, which I can open in VSCode and hit 'start' and it starts.  In AWS it's in CodeCommit and we use Amplify and Elastic Beanstalk?  I don't know whether that helps?

Comment: I've never used Amplify (which is what seems to be what is doing the "routing" work here) but I would imagine this is the place to look

Comment: Not sure about AWS CodeCommit repo, but you can try a similar [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69917945/4666303)