# How to put a React app in maintenance mode

Tags: reactjs, maintenance-mode

I want to know how to put a React app in maintenance mode.

Comment: What do you mean by a maintenance mode? You generally serve a React app as static (HTML, CSS, JS, ...) files, so a deployment doesn't take much time or effort.

Comment: Please see [ask]. You need to be more specific and provide some information about your app.

Comment: Similar to [this question asked about an hour ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69917214/how-can-i-create-a-holding-page-in-my-react-app).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create a component that will have the content to show when the application is in maintenance mode, and use it as the only component to be rendered in case of maintenance else other/normal behavior components. [codesandbox-demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-christian-4qxo5?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Exactly what was needed !

Comment: is this example for manual trigger? so we must change const maintenance true/false?